# Acting on sql result row count

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm starting with this query:

```
SELECT     TOP 1 Parties.FirstName + ' ' + Parties.MiddleName + ' ' + Parties.LastName AS     Plaintiffs
FROM         Jackets INNER JOIN
                  JacketPartyLinks ON Jackets.Id =     JacketPartyLinks.Jacket_JacketPartyLink INNER JOIN
                      Parties ON Parties.Id = JacketPartyLinks.JacketPartyLink_Party
WHERE     (Jackets.Id = @JacketID) AND (JacketPartyLinks.Role = 0)
```

What I'd like to accomplish is to take a count of what's returned, and if it's one row, do nothing. If it's more than one row, add something like ", et al". Notice that this query returns a single column, and it while it should be able to run standalone, it also needs to work as a subquery.

How can this be done?

**EDIT:** Add TOP 1

Comment: Are you trying to concatenate all the rows as a comma separated list, and if there are more than one, add, ", et al"? Or what? You can just do `select count(1) as mycount from...` if you just need to count the rows...

Comment: No, I don't need to concatenate. I just adjusted the query to show I really only want to return the first row, but if there is indeed more than one row, then I want to add on ", et al" to the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `top` and `count..over` and then wrap it in an outer query, like so:

```
select
    Plantiffs + case when PlantiffCount > 1 then ', et al' else '' end as Plantiffs
from
    (
        SELECT TOP 1
            Parties.FirstName + ' ' + Parties.MiddleName + ' ' + Parties.LastName as Plantiffs,
            count(1) over () as PlantiffCount
        FROM
            Jackets 
            INNER JOIN JacketPartyLinks ON 
                Jackets.Id = JacketPartyLinks.Jacket_JacketPartyLink 
            INNER JOIN Parties ON 
                Parties.Id = JacketPartyLinks.JacketPartyLink_Party
        WHERE
            (Jackets.Id = @JacketID) AND (JacketPartyLinks.Role = 0)
        order by Parties.LastName asc
    ) x
```

The `over ()` part after `count` tells it to count all rows and not `group by` anything. This is why there isn't a `group by` clause in that query. You can use `over` with any aggregate function, which is pretty nifty.

Comment: Ok, well, it seemed like it was going to work. Now it's saying that I need to declare the scalar variable @JacketID. Is there some trick to getting parameters in there? It seems to be OVER that's causing it to break.

Comment: @kettch - How are you loading that parameter? A similar query works fine for me with C# and adding the parameter to the `SqlCommand` object.

Comment: Maybe it's just the query processors in Visual Studio and SQL Server Management Studio. I was piecing together my components, and they both throw an error there. I'll try it out in code and see what happens. **EDIT**: Confirmed. VS and SSMS don't support OVER in their query editors, so it makes all kinds of things break. It works fine when it's run from code, as you mentioned. Thanks again!